# Create a SilverLight application and use SharePoint Object Model inside

Tags: 2007

The idea is to create a SilverLight 3 Application (not a web part) that will be used inside SharePoint 2007 (not a web part but a full aspx page that will be called from a Sharepoint feature), for example, a silverlight application that lists all documents of a SharePoint document Library, and when double-clicking an item it will display it.

How do I use the SharePoint object model (spsite, spweb, splist etc...) inside this SL app?
Is it not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you are suggesting you would need access to the Client Object Model which is only available from SharePoint 2010.

However you could use the web services to perform your underlying data accesss to SharePoint from within Silverlight 3 in MOSS or WSS 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that Silverlight runs on the client and not on the server. Because of this, the Sharepoint object model is not readily available to client-side apps.

As Charles Lee has already said, the way to do in '2007 is via web services. I believe that there is improved object model support in the 2010 version.

Answer (score 0):

Can u include Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll in your application and refer the Sharepoint object model. I have not done this . but looks like this should be the solution

Comment: This cannot be done! The Microsoft.SharePoint.dll can only be used on the servers where SharePoint is installed

Comment: correct, if we do development in Virtual PC that has the Sharepoint infrastructure the development can happen.